# Mediator vs CQRS vs Repository

Tags: sql, .net, design-pattern, orm

Olá,

Estou a desenvolver um migração para um novo ORM, em .NET, de uma aplicação com uma base de dados SQL complexa, muitas pequenas tabelas entre elas. Um sistema muitissimo acoplado.

De forma a organizar melhor o desenvolvimento queria implementar uma pattern. Alguma recomendaçáo? Estive a ver o **mediator**, o **CQRS**, o **repository**. Os três paracem-me bem, dado o caso de uma base de dados complexa, com muitas pequenas tabelas ligadas entre si, algum que seja mais adequado?

Obrigado.

Comment: Confesso que fiquei um bom tempo pensando no que escrever, pq (p mim) essa é uma questão com bom potencial, mas que muito provavelmente será fechada. Talvez se fosse separada ou colocada de outra forma facilitasse.

Comment: Quanto às 3 patterns, não vejo muita relação (de comparação) entre elas. Tem objetivos e usos completamente diferentes e pode-se até usar todas ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @tvdias Percebo o que dizes em relação às patterns. Tenho uma certa dificuldade em escolher patterns, à primeira vista as três funcionariam bem. No caso de uma base de dados muito acoplada, onde o código actual é um verdadeiro spaghetti code com inumeras classes a representar a minima informação. Recomendas algum pattern?